# Is it safe to reference an object's properties by index?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, indexing

Consider, I have this object:

```
var ob = {
  "page1.html" : {...},
  "page2.html" : {...},
  "page3.html" : {...}
}
```

I am unable to change this to an array, I don't have access to that, what I'd like to know is if it is safe to access the object properties by index, so:

```
var obVal = ob[0]; // reliably returns "page1.html"'s value every time
```

I know that a for each loop shouldn't be used in this situation because the values are hashed or something? But reference by index might be ok?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, `ob[0]` won't even work - it will give `undefined`. In fact if your object was:

```
var ob = {
  "0": "blah",
  "page1.html" : {...},
  "page2.html" : {...},
  "page3.html" : {...}
}
```

`ob[0]` will give you `"blah"`.

A for-each loop *is* the right tool for this situation, but you should just check that each index in the loop actually belongs to the object, and not to a parent:

```
for (var i in ob) { // i will be "page1.html", "page2.html", etc...
    if (!ob.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
    // Do something with ob[i]
}
```

Comment: interesting, thanks. now, I simply cannot find the link but someone on SO commented on a question regarding javascript arrays versus object references - and compared them. he said that one was like the other... ahh this isn't clarifying at all. but hey if you're reading buddy, you also wrote an article about the Voyager spacecraft and how it was approaching the interstellar boundary... he basically said using a for in loop wasn't always reliable. I wish I could find that article, because it is what prompted me to ask  :/

Comment: @Danjah Well, order isn't guaranteed if that is what you are wondering. Or maybe you are worried about Object getting extended, the hasOwnProperty will take care of that.

Comment: Yeah, order is definitely important here, sorry I thought that was clear - yeah order please!

Comment: @Danjah, I think what you want is: `ob["page" + (i - 1) + ".html"]`. However, to clarify, when @Hemlock says that there's no guarantee of order, he means that you *cannot* get order out of associate arrays. That is, `{a: 1, b: 2}` is the same as `{b: 2, a: 1}`. Therefore, `ob[0]` doesn't make sense. However you can *simulate* order by defining your own rule, as I've done above.

Comment: Hey! I found the link: http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/11/myths-and-realities-of-forin.html